# Is there an un-informed version of "etc."?

Tags: synonyms

I'm updating my resume, and I'm explaining what fields of mathematics I have experience teaching.

I list a few, but I want to add something like "etc." to clarify that the list is "including, but not limited to" the mentioned examples.

Like if I say;

> [...] teaching mathematics, such as arithmetic, algebra, calculus, linear algebra, **etc.**, [...]

It just seems like "etc." implies that the reader is aware of the rest.

I've considered "and more", but it seems like something you hear in commercials and sales-pitches.

I've also considered preceding it with "including, but not limited to...", but that makes it sound like something you'd read in a contract or another legal document.

I might be overly caught up in this, but it's my resume, and you will probably understand that it is quite important for me to get it just right.

Comment: _And others_? (you could use _and such_ but I wouldn't do that is you start with _such as_)

Comment: In my opinion, the phrase "such as" already implies that the list will not be complete. So I would simply write "such as arithmetic, algebra, calculus, and linear algebra."

Comment: Aside: Personally I wouldn't bother listing such basic and general mathematical areas. It's more important to say what level(s) you've taught at (and that's more-than-likely going to make it abundantly clear that you've taught some arithmetic, calculus, algebra, etc).

Comment: @Rupe - That is actually a very good point. The thing is, when listing university-level fields, one simply has to be more specific, because teaching the entire university level of mathematics is impossible, and the differences matter a lot. With that said, I will generalize it for the lower levels. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Oh absolutely, you want to show any specialisation you've done. Those basic areas don't really count as specialisation. Whereas, for example, teaching to young children *is* a specialisation (I'm assuming that your arithmetic teaching wasn't at university level).

Comment: *...algebra, calculus, linear algebra et al.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just say *including*.

> [...] teaching mathematics, including arithmetic, algebra, calculus, and linear algebra. [...]

Doesn't have the legalese smack of "including, but not limited to", but still means the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

In a resume avoid **etc.**.

> mathematics, such as arithmetic, algebra, calculus, linear algebra,
>   etc.

'such as' indicates 'not limited to'. Do not patronise your reader.